# How to force source code to be written LTR in a RTL document?

Tags: xetex, listings, polyglossia, right-to-left, bidi

I am writing an Arabic book in LaTeX where I have to put much C code in it. I am compiling it using XeLaTeX. To have a proper Arabic support I use `polyglossia` package. For source code, I use `listings`, and to control the direction of the text I use `bidi`. The problem is that I can't make the source code looks really LTR. This screenshot shows all what I could do :

[image: Source code screenshot]

As you can see, the symbols `<> () {}` are inverted and written in RTL mode. This is some of the code I am currently using :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bidi}
% And other packages ...
\setmainlanguage[locale=algeria]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Arial}
% ...
\lstset{language=C, showstringspaces=false, frame=single, numbers=left,
    breaklines=true, keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{Blue}, commentstyle=\color{LightGray},
    numberstyle=\color{Gray}, stringstyle=\color{Yellow}, basicstyle=\ttfamily, morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}}
\lstnewenvironment{Csource}{\setLTR}{\unsetLTR}
% ...
\begin{Csource}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

\end{Csource}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case better use of

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt{Courier New}
```

Rather then

```
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
```

And you can remove `bidi`  pachage which is loaded by default in case of RTL languages with `polyglossia`

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
% And other packages ...
\setmainlanguage[locale=algeria]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Arial}
% ...
\lstset{language=C, showstringspaces=false, frame=single, numbers=left,
    breaklines=true, keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},basicstyle=\ttfamily, commentstyle=\color{LightGray},
    numberstyle=\color{gray}, stringstyle=\color{yellow},  morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}}
\lstnewenvironment{Csource}{\setLTR}{\unsetLTR}
% ...

\begin{document}


\begin{Csource}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

\end{Csource}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]