Border of a listing is broken
I have this code:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,bidi=default]{babel}        % Typeset Arabic
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}              % Typeset Arabic
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}    % Typeset Arabic {Arabic Typesetting}

\usepackage{listings} % Typeset Code

\usepackage{xcolor} 

% Define Python typeset format
\lstdefinestyle{mypython}{
    language=Python,                            % Python language syntax
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,                 % Basic font style (tt = monospaced)
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},         % Keywords in bold blue
    stringstyle=\color{green},          % Strings in green
    commentstyle=\color{red},           % Comments in gray
    numbers=left,                               % Line numbers on the left
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{green},   % Line numbers style
    stepnumber=1,                               % Number every line
    numbersep=4mm,                              % Space between numbers and code
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % Light gray background
    identifierstyle=\color{purple},     % Set color for identifiers purple (variable names)
    showstringspaces=false,                     % Don't show spaces in strings
    frame=single,                               % Box around the code
    rulecolor=\color{green},                % Color of the box around the code 
    framesep=3mm,                               % Padding around code
    breaklines=true,                            % Break long lines
    breakatwhitespace=true,                     % Break only at whitespace
    tabsize=5,                                  % Set tab size to 4 spaces
    aboveskip=10pt,                             % Space above the code
    belowskip=10pt,                             % Space below the code
    captionpos=b, 
}
% Set "mypython" as the default style
\lstset{style=mypython}

\begin{document}
\chapter{مثال}

هذا مثال لكود بايثون بسيط
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a simple addition program, the program askes user to input two values, then it addes them, then it displays the result.
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
result = num1 + num2
print("The result is:", result)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}

Which produce the following listings with the problems circled in red:

I have searched for a solution or eve an explanation for that but did not found any.
I would heighly appreciate your help

I think it's a problem with babel/arabic, because if I turn your document to fully English, it works correctly (I can't help you because I don't have the font you're using, sorry).

Thank you  CarLaTeX, actually, I must thank you for your answer, and for correcting my question.
I totally agree it is because of babel/arabic, I hope someone here has had this problem before and got it fixed.

Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319089/how-to-force-source-code-to-be-written-ltr-in-a-rtl-document help?

XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Thank you Javier Bezos, I am using LuaTeX

I have to investigate what listings is doing.

Thank you Skillmon, I tried to use the solution in the link you provided, but I am using "babel" package instead of "polyglossia", and I think this is what prevented this solution from working in my case

@Emad It seems listings uses \parshape to format the code, and sadly this command is a bit problematic in luatex. If you set \shapemode=2, the border is correct, but the text is somewhat misaligned. I wonder if the latter is related to a long standing bug in luatex described in the babel manual.

Thanks again @JavierBezos, I appreciate your efforts. I think I will try XelaTex then, I will let you know.

@JavierBezos Using XelaTex solved this problem, but it changed the alignment of some parts of my document, not all parts, I am going to check what parts changed.

@Emad Sorry, but I think I misunderstood what the required format was. I thought the Python comment had to be aligned to the right (as in the image), and the only problem was the displaced rules (which is what the title says). If you confirm the second and third lines have to be indented, I’ll convert my comments into an answer.

Thank you @JavierBezos, you are right, the image is misleading, I am sorry about that, I would love to see your answer.

@JavierBezos Is that bug you claim reported somewhere? I cannot trigger it in context.

@mickep See https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2019-April/007126.html. There was some reminder, I’m not sure where.

You can use tcolorbox for the frame.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,bidi=default]{babel}        % Typeset Arabic
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}              % Typeset Arabic
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}    % Typeset Arabic {Arabic Typesetting}

\usepackage{listings} % Typeset Code
\usepackage[many,listings]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xcolor} 

% Define Python typeset format
\lstdefinestyle{mypython}{
    language=Python,                    % Python language syntax
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,         % Basic font style (tt = monospaced)
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue}, % Keywords in bold blue
    stringstyle=\color{green},          % Strings in green
    commentstyle=\color{red},           % Comments in gray
    numbers=left,                       % Line numbers on the left
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{green},     % Line numbers style
    stepnumber=1,                       % Number every line
    numbersep=4mm,                      % Space between numbers and code
%    backgroundcolor=\color{white},      % Light gray background
    identifierstyle=\color{purple},     % Set color for identifiers purple (variable names)
    showstringspaces=false,             % Don't show spaces in strings
%    frame=single,                       % Box around the code
%    rulecolor=\color{green},            % Color of the box around the code 
%    framesep=3mm,                       % Padding around code
    breaklines=true,                    % Break long lines
    breakatwhitespace=true,             % Break only at whitespace
    tabsize=5,                          % Set tab size to 4 spaces
%    aboveskip=10pt,                     % Space above the code
%    belowskip=10pt,                     % Space below the code
    captionpos=b, 
}

\NewTCBListing{mylisting}{!O{}}{
  colback=white,
  colframe=green,
  sharp corners,
  boxsep=-2mm,
  listing only,
  listing options={style=mypython,#1},
}
\AddToHook{env/mylisting/before}{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}
\AddToHook{env/mylisting/after}{\end{otherlanguage}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{مثال}

هذا مثال لكود بايثون بسيط

\begin{mylisting}
# This is a simple addition program, the program asks user to input two values, then it adds them, then it displays the result.
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
result = num1 + num2
print("The result is:", result)
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}



Thank you @egreg, this solution is very nice, it even gave me more formatting options.

[Note. The image and the title is somewhat misleading. The problem is the whole block is shifted to the left.]
listings formats the code using \parshape, which is somewhat problematic in luatex. Although babel modifies the lists environments to adjust its behavior (there are no other uses in the LaTeX kernel, iir), there can be packages relying on this command. In order to adjust the exact bahavior, luatex provides \shapemode. In this case, the following fix the problem:
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\shapemode=2
\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a simple addition program, the program askes user to input two values, then it addes them, then it displays the result.
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
result = num1 + num2
print("The result is:", result)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{otherlanguage}

Alternatively, if you are using english just to wrap listings, you can add in the preamble:
\AddBabelHook[english]{shape}{afterextras}{\shapemode=2\relax}


You are right @Javier Bezos, I do apologize for that, I thought circling the problem would explain it all, but it did not.
